# Error : java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError with Charuco Camera Calibration (DetectorParameters)

Tags: java, opencv, camera, camera-calibration, aruco

Good morning everyone. I am currently working on a project in which I have to detect object coordinates within an image with high precision. I have tried using a normal chessboard for camera calibration but the reprojection error was too high so I decided to use the Charuco calibration pattern. I am working with OpenCv 3.4 and Java (project constraint). Since the Aruco function are not included in OpenCv for Java I created a new package in my project which includes the necessary classes. The Aruco code is the one that you can find in the following link :
[Aruco Code Github](https://github.com/chaoyangnz/opencv3-android-sdk-with-contrib/tree/master/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/java/src/org/opencv/aruco)

The code that I'm executing is the following:

```
protected void captureImagesCharuco() {
    int squaresX = 5;
    int squaresY = 7;
    float squareLength = (float) 37.0;
    float markerLength = (float) 22.0;
    int calibrationFlags = 0;
    float aspectRatio = 1;
    DetectorParameters detectParams = DetectorParameters.create();
    detectParams.set_adaptiveThreshWinSizeMin(3);
    detectParams.set_adaptiveThreshWinSizeMax(23);
    detectParams.set_adaptiveThreshWinSizeStep(10);
    detectParams.set_adaptiveThreshConstant(7);
    detectParams.set_minMarkerPerimeterRate(0.03);
    detectParams.set_maxMarkerPerimeterRate(4.0);
    detectParams.set_polygonalApproxAccuracyRate(0.05);
    detectParams.set_minCornerDistanceRate(10);
    detectParams.set_minDistanceToBorder(3);
    detectParams.set_minMarkerDistanceRate(0.05);
    detectParams.set_cornerRefinementWinSize(5);
    detectParams.set_cornerRefinementMaxIterations(30);
    detectParams.set_cornerRefinementMinAccuracy(0.1);
    detectParams.set_markerBorderBits(1);
    detectParams.set_perspectiveRemovePixelPerCell(8);
    detectParams.set_perspectiveRemoveIgnoredMarginPerCell(0.13);
    detectParams.set_maxErroneousBitsInBorderRate(0.04);
    detectParams.set_minOtsuStdDev(5.0);
    detectParams.set_errorCorrectionRate(0.6);
    Dictionary dictionary = Aruco.getPredefinedDictionary(0);
    CharucoBoard charucoBoard = CharucoBoard.create(squaresX, squaresY, squareLength, markerLength, dictionary);
    List<List<Mat>> charucoCorners = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Mat> charucoIds = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Mat> validImgs = new ArrayList<>();
    Size imgSize = new Size();
    int nFrame = 0;
    
    File[] listImages = imageDirectory.listFiles();
    for(File file : listImages) {
        String src = file.getAbsolutePath();
        Mat imgRead = Imgcodecs.imread(src,Imgcodecs.IMREAD_COLOR);
        imgSize = imgRead.size();
        Mat imgCopy = new Mat();
        Mat ids = new Mat();
        List<Mat> rejectedCorners = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Mat> corners = new ArrayList<>();
        if (!imgRead.empty()){ 
            Aruco.detectMarkers(imgRead, dictionary, corners, ids);
            Aruco.refineDetectedMarkers(imgRead, (Board)charucoBoard, corners, ids, rejectedCorners);
            Mat currentCharucoCorners = new Mat();
            Mat currentCharucoIds = new Mat();
            int idsSize = ids.rows()*ids.cols();
            if(idsSize>0) {
                Aruco.interpolateCornersCharuco(corners, ids, imgRead, charucoBoard, currentCharucoCorners, currentCharucoIds);
            }
            imgRead.copyTo(imgCopy);
            if(idsSize<0) {
                Aruco.drawDetectedCornersCharuco(imgCopy, currentCharucoCorners);
            }
            if(currentCharucoCorners.total()>0) {
                Aruco.drawDetectedCornersCharuco(imgCopy, currentCharucoCorners, currentCharucoIds, new Scalar(255,0,0));
            }
            charucoCorners.add(corners);
            charucoIds.add(currentCharucoIds);
            validImgs.add(imgRead);
            nFrame++;
        }
        
    }
    
    intrinsic.put(0, 0, 1);
    intrinsic.put(1, 1, 1);
    List<Mat> allCharucoCorners = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Mat> allCharucoIds = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i =0;i<nFrame;i++) {
        Mat currentCharucoCorners = new Mat();
        Mat currentCharucoIds = new Mat();
        Aruco.interpolateCornersCharuco(charucoCorners.get(i), charucoIds.get(i), validImgs.get(i), charucoBoard, currentCharucoCorners, currentCharucoIds,intrinsic,distCoeffs,4);
        allCharucoCorners.add(currentCharucoCorners);
        allCharucoIds.add(currentCharucoIds);
    }
    double repError = Aruco.calibrateCameraCharuco(allCharucoCorners, charucoIds, charucoBoard, imgSize, intrinsic, distCoeffsCharuco, rvecs, tvecs, calibrationFlags);
    System.out.println("reprojection error : " + repError);
}
```

I then simply execute the captureImagesCharuco() in the main program. However when I do so I get the following error :

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: application.DetectorParameters.create_0()J
at application.DetectorParameters.create_0(Native Method)
at application.DetectorParameters.create(DetectorParameters.java:24)
at application.CameraCalibrate.captureImagesCharuco(CameraCalibrate.java:115)
at application.Main.main(Main.java:64)
... 11 more
Exception running application application.Main
```

I have tried searching for how to solve this error (UnsatisfiedLinkError) and I found that it is usually caused when you're using a library that isn't included in the Build Path or the project (Even though I ma not sure). I guess the library in question here is the Aruco package but I don't know how I can include a package in the build path of the project.

Any kind of help will be more than welcome ! Thank you ! :)

Comment: I'm guessing you are using some custom opencv package. Have you tried building opencv from source with that package selected? I believe that in that case java package will be created with the functionality you need linked (https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d52/tutorial_java_dev_intro.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I belive you are right, after some digging it turned out the module I am trying to use is part of the opencv-contrib library so I have to build it correctly using Cmake. I haven't done it yet but I am currently working on it (turns out it's a bit of a ehadache to do it on windows), I'll post about it if it works.

Comment: There's very likely some prebuilt contrib packages for java (like [this maybe?](https://github.com/chegel/OpenCV-3.4.0-windows-x64) ), but it's a good practice to build it on your own.

Comment: Thank you for the link. It took me some time to answer because I wanted to try and build it on my own, but it was a living hell and I've been working on it since yesterday without results so I gave up so I used the prebuilt library you gave me. That solved my problem tho, so thanks again ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that you have opencv package without special module you're using;

In order to fix that you'd need to either find a prebuilt opencv with module you need (in your exactly case it's lcoated in contrib library, so [this](https://github.com/chegel/OpenCV-3.4.0-windows-x64) probably helps.

In case you want to build it from sources - you should enable the module you want in cmake properties. For contrib - you'd need to cmake contrib project first & then enable contrib in main opencv makefile. For building opencv & contirb - please follow official documentation.